# Не могу понять как сложить сумму из двух массивов на определенных условиях

Tags: java, массивы

Задано массивы А (n) и В (n). Сформировать массив С (n) следующим способом: элемент массива С равен сумме соответствующих элементов массивов А и В, если оба элемента положительные; элемент массива С равен произведению соответствующих элементов массивов А и В, если оба элемента отрицательные; элемент массива С равен нулю во всех других случаях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код должен быть простым и понятным, без этих ваших условий, в которых чёрт ногу сломит ;)
[ideone](https://ideone.com/g52Kpv)

```
    int[] A = {2, 2, 2, -2, -2, -2,  0, 0, 0};
    int[] B = {3, -3, 0, 3, -3,  0, 3, -3, 0};
    int[] C = new int[9];
    for(int i=0;  i < A.length; i++){

        int s = (Integer.signum(A[i]) + Integer.signum(B[i])) / 2;
        C[i] = (s + 1) / 2 * (A[i] + B[i])  + (1 - s) / 2 * (A[i] * B[i]);

        System.out.println(C[i]);
    }

 >>     5 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] > 0 && b[i] > 0 ? a[i] + b[i] :
            a[i] < 0 && b[i] < 0 ? a[i] * b[i] :
                    0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  if (a[i]>0 && b[i]>0) {
    c[i] = a[i]+b[i];
    } else if(a[i]<0 && b[i}<0) {
      c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: никогда не используй в своем коде столько if/ else глаза режет

Comment: в своем коде я не использую столько if/else, но просто чтобы избежать объяснений автору вопроса смысл тернарных выражений, как работают и прочие тонкости написал так))) я думаю автору этого за глаза) но твой код плюсанул :)

Comment: @Санаев, буков больше, но код с `if-else if-else` читается и понимается проще, чем Ваши вложенные тернарные операторы.

Comment: @JIeIIIa кто вам такое сказал?

Comment: @Санаев, например, [To ternary or not to ternary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160218/to-ternary-or-not-to-ternary).

Comment: @JIeIIIa кому как . достаточно правильно сделать разделение и будет достаточно хорошо читаться